# Java regex match wikipedia link

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a java regular expression to extract text from wikipedia links, but I'm coming up short.

In essence I want to extract `<article alias>` from `[[Some Article|<article alias>]]`. The sequence `[[<Any article>|<any alias>]]` will show up an unknown amount of times for any given string.

Basically I'm looking for a regular expression to put in `<regexp here>`:

```
final String someRandomText = "Some random text about [[Roman Empire|the romans]]";
final String replaced = someRandomText.replaceAll("<regexp here>", "$1");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Will the original text contain *sqaure brackets* ? Try using this `(?<=\|).*?(?=])`. In order to be sure that the `regex` will work, I will be needing more information.

Comment: Do you want to extract all aliases to a List, preserve only aliases as a space delimited list, or replace them? Please give an example of what you expect `replaced` to be.

Comment: When you have clarified what you want, please vote to reopen your question. As it stands, it is unclear what you want.

Answer (score 5):

By using the regex, `\[\[[^|]*\|(.*)\]\]` you can retrieve group(1) from the matched text.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[[^|]*\\|(.*)\\]\\]")
                .matcher("Some random text about [[Roman Empire|the romans]]");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
the romans
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0CQTpA/1):**

[image]

Comment: OP says: *The sequence [[<Any article>|<any alias>]] will show up **an unknown amount of times** for any given string.* Wouldn't a loop be required?

Comment: @Bohemian - Thanks for pointing it out. I'll update the answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: You may want to wait for OP to respond to my request for clarification comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match that format, you might also use a capture group.

```
\[\[[^|]+\|(.+?)]]
```

- `\[\[` Match `[[`
- `[^|]+\|` Match 1+ times any char except `|`, then match the `|`
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**, match as least as possible chars
- `]]` Match `]]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK6DGd/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/0Y87ko)

Example code

```
String regex = "\\[\\[[^|]+\\|(.+?)]]";
String string = "Some random text about [[Roman Empire|the romans]] test Some random text about [[Another Empire|the romans 2]]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
the romans
the romans 2
```

---

If you want to use `replaceAll` for the given example, you can match as least as possible chars up to the pattern, and then replace with group 1 using `$1`

```
final String someRandomText = "Some random text about [[Roman Empire|the romans]]";
final String replaced = someRandomText.replaceAll(".*?\\[\\[[^|]+\\|(.+?)]]", "$1");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output

```
the romans
```

Comment: OP says: *The sequence [[<Any article>|<any alias>]] will show up **an unknown amount of times** for any given string.* Wouldn't a loop be required?

Comment: @Bohemian Oh yes, in that case for the finding multiple it would be `while (matcher.find()) {`

Comment: You may want to wait for OP to respond to my request for clarification comment.

Comment: @Bohemian Reading `show up an unknown amount of times` in the question, I think you are right.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I don't remember anymore :-) but the question seems pretty clear to me.